# Difference in file count (Linux and Windows)

Tags: files

When I run a Windows command prompt which gives me the total number of files on my hard drive, the number is very different from when I run it on the same hard drive using Ubuntu. Ubuntu is showing a great deal more files.

Does anyone know any potential causes for this? Is Windows unable to see some files?

The commands used in Ubuntu `-type f | wc -l` and Windows `dir *.* /w /s /a`.

Comment: Without knowing what commands you ran, and what their output is, it's not possible to answer. [Edit] your question to include the commands and the output of them.

Comment: So if windows shows less files blame windows? Not our problem ;) Windows is infamous for hiding things from the user so why not files?

Comment: Out of memory; `dir /b /s /a-d` would be similar to `find type -f` ... I'm not entirely sure what you have tried, as you have neither of these in your question.

Comment: **Close voters:** We have many questions in AU on how to get Ubuntu to access Windows files. There are  a few questions on getting Windows to access Ubuntu files. All are valid and on-topic so far.

Answer (score 1):

Windows cannot see the Ubuntu files, so you are getting count of Windows files **only**.

Ubuntu can see Windows, so you are getting file count of Windows **plus** Ubuntu.

Note that within Ubuntu you can get different file counts using different commands. For example:

```
rick@alien:~$ ls /mnt
c  d  e
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ locate * | wc -l
861646
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ find / * 2>/dev/null | wc -l
1262530
```

- Notice there are three Windows NTFS partitions that Ubuntu *"sees"*.
- The `locate` command only counts 861,646 files. It excludes Ubuntu system files and `/tmp` directory files. It includes Windows though.
- The `find` command counts 1,262,530 files and directories. It is also includes Windows plus Ubuntu system files and the `/tmp` directory files.

Comment: Your `find` also counts directories and objects below `/dev` and `/run`. I doubt your `locate` considers them.

Comment: @PerlDuck Yes a directory is a file and yes Locate doesn't track them like Find. Each directory also has a `.` (current directory) and a `..` (parent directory) file. Interesting to point on Ubuntu 16.40 locate reports 1,552,100 files. The example above was generated on test partition after full clone of 16.04 then upgrade to 18.04 which removed 233 packages. One of them was `gksu` (boo-hoo :().